# Apple Mach-O Linker Error : Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, linker-errors

Although there are already lots of similar questions here, I still can't solve this issue.

I'm developing some application of IOS and most of the file is written by Object-C. But
I need to use some algorithm about FFT, so I created a C file(include head file) to calculate
it. When I tried to compile it into IOS Device, I got an Apple Mach-O Linker Error.

Because I can post any image, so I copy the log here.
Sorry about that.
it seems like that:

```
     Ld /Users/nekonosukiyaki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Decode-eqksrmyvutoiidgpubzmnxbofxmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Decode.app/Decode normal armv7
            cd /Users/nekonosukiyaki/Mr.WORK/MyProjects/IOS/Decode
            export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
            export PATH="
                        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"       
                        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot 
                        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/nekonosukiyaki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Decode-eqksrmyvutoiidgpubzmnxbofxmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/nekonosukiyaki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Decode-eqksrmyvutoiidgpubzmnxbofxmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/nekonosukiyaki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Decode-eqksrmyvutoiidgpubzmnxbofxmr/Build/Intermediates/Decode.build/Debug-iphoneos/Decode.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Decode.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nekonosukiyaki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Decode-eqksrmyvutoiidgpubzmnxbofxmr/Build/Intermediates/Decode.build/Debug-iphoneos/Decode.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Decode_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nekonosukiyaki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Decode-eqksrmyvutoiidgpubzmnxbofxmr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Decode.app/Decode

        Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
          "rdft(int, int, double*, int*, double*)", referenced from:
              ___31-[ViewController pushStartBTN:]_block_invoke in ViewController.o
        ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not good at English but I'm trying to do my best to let you know about my problem.
Again, Thank you very much.

(a)in my .h file:

```
void cdft(int n, int isgn, double *a, int *ip, double *w);
void rdft(int n, int isgn, double *a, int *ip, double *w);
void ddct(int n, int isgn, double *a, int *ip, double *w);
void ddst(int n, int isgn, double *a, int *ip, double *w);
void dfct(int n, double *a, double *t, int *ip, double *w);
void dfst(int n, double *a, double *t, int *ip, double *w);
```

(b)in .c file

```
void rdft(int n, int isgn, double *a, int *ip, double *w)
{
    void makewt(int nw, int *ip, double *w);
    void makect(int nc, int *ip, double *c);
...
```

(c)in .m file

```
- (IBAction)pushStartBTN:(UIButton *)sender {
    Novocaine *audioManager = [Novocaine audioManager];
    self.audioManager = audioManager;
    [self.audioManager setInputBlock:^(float *newAudio, UInt32 numSamples, UInt32 numChannels) {
        // Now you're getting audio from the microphone every 20 milliseconds or so. How's that for easy?
        // Audio comes in interleaved, so,
        // if numChannels = 2, newAudio[0] is channel 1, newAudio[1] is channel 2, newAudio[2] is channel 1, etc.

//        NSLog(@"newAudio: %f, numSamples: %u, numChannnels: %u",*newAudio,(unsigned int)numSamples,(unsigned int)numChannels);
        double data[numSamples * 2];
        int *ip = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (2 + sqrt((double)(numSamples*2))));
        double *w = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * (numSamples));
        ip[0] = 0;
        double *spectrum = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*512);

        if (numChannels == 2) {
            NSLog(@"2 channels and quit");
        }
        else {
            for (int i=0; i<numSamples; i++) {
                data[i<<1] = newAudio[i] * _window.win[i];
                data[(i<<1)+1] = 0;
            }
            rdft(numSamples*2, 1, (double *)data, ip, w);
        }
        for (int i=400; i<470; i++) {
            spectrum[i] = 10*log10(pow(data[i<<1], 2)+pow(data[(i<<1)+1], 2));
        }
        Threshold *threshold = [[Threshold alloc]initWithTrig:spectrum[450] :spectrum[454] :0.9];
        [threshold calThresByIREF];
        NSLog(@"threshold: %f",threshold.threshold);
    }];
    [self.audioManager play];
}
```

(d)I can't compile .c along but the function in .c file was written by 
a professor and it can works well if I use it just in a C program.

as the code is so long that I can't copy it all here.I'm so sorry about it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is `rdft` defined ? Is it in a .c file or a .cpp file ? Do you have a .h header file for it ? Have you `#include`d the .h file where it's being called from ? Is the .c/.cpp file being compiled ?

Comment: rdft is a function which is a kind of FFT algorithm actually, and it is defined in a .c file. I have all .c .h files and #include them all. I use this function in my ViewController.mm

Comment: I think you're going to need to include in the question: (a) the prototype for `rdft` as declared in your .h file, (b) the first part of the definition of `rdft` from your .c file, (c) the line where you call `rdft` from your Objective-C .m file, and (d) any warnings generated when you compile these files.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't compile your .c file ?

Comment: Sorry my fault. I compiled it and succeeded.So there is no warning here.

Comment: OK - a few final questions and then I'm stumped: is there anything else in your .h file, other than the `rdft` prototype ? Does your .c file #include your .h file ? Does your .m file #include your .h file ?

Comment: Yes, I updated all of them in my question. However, I tried to leave just rdft prototype before, but the same problem.
Thank you for your patience Paul R

Comment: Adrian, is this a case of a missing `extern "C" { /* Function declarations */ }`? Is the header wrapped in `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif` and `#ifdef __cplusplus } #endif`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't write it. Where should I add it? Iwillnotexist Idonotexist
I will try to add it in my head file and report later. Thank you very much

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: I know what you're thinking, but I don't think this should be necessary so long as it's being `#include`d in a .m file (and not a C++/.cpp or Objective-C++/.mm file). It does *look* like a C++ function is expected in the linker error message though...

Comment: @Adrian Like so: http://pastebin.com/bPyu7y4P The key is that an `extern "C"` must wrap all function declarations for functions compiled in C mode when the include is used in a language that mangles names.

Comment: @PaulR:I #include my .h file in my .c file and #include that .h file(rdft's head file) in .m file.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist:I tried to add it in its head file and amazingly it worked. I don't know why have to write it. Would you please tell me the reason? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Adrian The reason is that to support niceties like function/method overload, languages must "mangle" names internally to make them dependent on the # of arguments and their types. For instance in C++, GCC mangles functions by prefixing `_Z` to the name and postfixing with a large string that basically states the types of the arguments. But since these mangled names are different from the normal C name, the linker (which is so far down the chain it only sees mangled names) doesn't know what to do and chokes. `extern "C"` disables this mangling and makes it C-compatible.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist:So is it mean that the machine mangle it as C++ in default,and if I don't tell system "it's a C code", system can not mangle it?

Comment: In C++/ObjC/ObjC++ mode, the compiler will mangle. In C mode, it won't. Hence when you build your C file with `rdft()`'s definition, the compiler spits out the unmangled symbol. But when you include the header in a C++/ObjC/ObjC++ file __and don't mark it `extern "C"`__, then the compiler mangles the function name. So now the compiler built a function with the unmangled name, but now is compiling C++/ObjC/ObjC++ code that asks for it by a different, mangled name. The linker considers `rdft` and `_Zrdft8foo3bar3baz4quux` to be totally different, fails to connect the two, chokes and dies.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist:Oh,I see.Your explanation is so understandably.I'm so happy to solve this problem because I have worked on it all day.Thank you so much. I appreciate it very much. LOL

Comment: @PaulR:Thank you for your help and your patience.I learned a lot. Again, thank you very much. LOL